# How to register circuit breaker fallback using resilence4j api?

Tags: java, spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

Initially I used spring boot configuration for circuit breaker.

```
@CircuitBreaker(name = "myCircuitBreaker", fallbackMethod = "myFallbackMethod")
```

Then I realized that I need to create circuit breakers dynamically

I have a code like this:

```
CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = circuitBreakerRegistry.circuitBreaker(generateNameBasedOnInputArgumets());
Runnable decoratedRunnable = CircuitBreaker
        .decorateRunnable(circuitBreaker, () -> executeSomeCode());
Try.runRunnable(decoratedRunnable).getOrElseThrow(e -> {           
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
});
```

I can't understand how can I register analog of fallback method. Could you please give me a piece of advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the resilience4j Decorators.withFallback option? As mentioned here: https://reflectoring.io/circuitbreaker-with-resilience4j/
You can try something like decorating a Supplier for your service call

```
Supplier<String> supplier= () -> service.generateNameBasedOnInputArgumets(args);
Supplier<String> decoratedSupplier= Decorators
  .ofSupplier(supplier)
  .withCircuitBreaker(circuitBreaker)
  .withFallback(CallNotPermittedException.class,
                e -> myFallbackMethod())
  .decorate();
decoratedSupplier.get()
```

bear with any syntax errors, I didn't compile the above.